# Something is beeping in my house intermittently. It is not the smoke or carbon monoxide detectors!

Tags: battery, sounds

We are having a very infrequent beep occur in the house.  It lasts about one second and then stops for a long time, about once an hour or so.  I can't tell what direction it is coming from but we have checked all the smoke and carbon monoxide detectors.  We can hear it pretty clearly from the living room and dining room.

Comment: Is it a single, high-pitched beep like a smoke detector?  If not, how is it different?

Comment: A once per hour beep sounds a lot like a low battery indicator -- what else do you have running on batteries around the house?

Comment: How do you know it's not a smoke or CO detector?  If your smoke or CO detectors are older, the infrequent beep could also be an indication that they have reached the end of their useful life and need to be replaced.  CO detectors typically have about a 10-year lifetime on them, and have a built-in timer to know when that 10 years is up.  Also check if you have a UPS battery backup somewhere for your computer, sump pump, etc.  Without knowing what electrical items you have in your house, it's hard to know what it could be.

Answer (score 3):

> A once per hour beep sounds a lot like a low battery indicator -- what else do you have running on batteries around the house?

Some things to check:

- Internet/Phone - specifically in my area, Verizon FIOS often has a battery backup so that phones don't go out when the power goes out in order to better simulate [POTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service) Actually, in many recent FIOS installations they haven't bothered *because people wouldn't bother to replace the batteries*.
- Burglar Alarm
- UPS - Typically attached to a computer

Comment: If the OP has acute hearing, it could be an annoyatron: https://www.thegreenhead.com/2008/12/annoy-a-tron-2.php

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: a service reminder built into an appliance or as a separate small battery-powered device. It could be a reminder to check the salt level in a water softener or to check the filter in the furnace, for example.

Make note of the exact time when you hear the chirp a couple times. Compute the interval and check whether it is consistent (it probably is). Then you can forecast when a future chirp will occur and can be ready to listen for it and localize the source better.